# How can I get previous date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have tried below code to get previous date of a certain date:

```
var d = new Date("2019","12","21");
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1 );
alert(d.getFullYear()+"-"+d.getMonth()+"-"+d.getDate());
```

I expected this code to return: '`2019-12-20`'.
But it returns: '`2020-0-20`'.

Can somebody explain why this code working like this?
And how can I modify my code to get previous date?

Comment: There is no month 12, months go from 0 - 11, so 12=1 is February, -1 = January. January is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months are zero based. 0 is January, 11 is December, 12 is therefore January again. You go from 21st January to 20th January.

To work with one based months, you have to decrement when inserting the value into the date, and increment when reading from it:

```js
//                             v
const date = new Date(2019, 12 - 1, 21);
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);

//                                                      v
console.log(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have easier way to get the new date, like this:

```
let preDate =  new Date((new Date(2019, 12 - 1, 21).getTime()-24*3600))
console.log(preDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (preDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + preDate.getDate());
```